# Formulation of variable mass model at college level

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, momentum, conservation-laws

> A raindrop absorbs water as it falls vertically under gravity through
>   a cloud. In a model of the motion the cloud is assumed to consist of
>   stationary water particles. At time $t$, the mass of the raindrop is
>   $m$ and the speed of the raindrop is $v$. At time $t = 0$, the
>   raindrop is at rest. The rate of increase of the mass of the raindrop
>   with respect to time is modeled as being $mkv$, where $k$ is a
>   positive constant. Ignoring air resistance, show from first
>   principles, that
>
> $$  \frac{dv}{dt} = g - kv^2. $$

The accepted (and perhaps rather simplified) approach by use of impulse momentum theorem, that the change of linear momentum of the system in the time interval $\delta t$  is equal to the impulse of the external forces acting on the system in that time interval. Many textbooks apply this theorem as:

$$
mg\delta t = (m + \delta m)(v + \delta v) - mv - (\delta m)(0)
$$

**Question**

Why the left side is $mg\delta t$ rather than $(m+\delta m)g\delta t$ ?

(Is it because the staitionary particles are at rest and thus it is assumed that, at least for the purpose of this simplieifed model) there is no force acting on them?)

Curiously, some few textbooks write the above relation as:

$$
(m+\delta m)g\delta t = (m + \delta m)(v + \delta v) - mv - (\delta m)(0)
$$

But then when both sides are divided by $\delta t$, and then taking the limit as:
$$
\displaystyle\lim_{t \to 0}(mg + g\delta m)
$$

The $g\delta m$ term mysteriously (at least, for me) disappears. Why?

**Question**

What does the limit has to do with $g\delta m$ when there is no $\delta t$ term?

Comment: Could also be that $\delta t\delta m$ is second order while others are first, no?

Comment: Quote taken from where?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you sum two quantities, and one of them is infinitesimal compared to the other, the small term will disappear unless the large term is subtracted out elsewhere. A priori you may not know that it disappears, and so you keep your term around until you are done cancelling things. At that point, all higher order terms can be assumed to be zero.

You said "the term $g\delta m$ mysteriously (at least, for me) disappears. Why?"

When we allow $\delta t$ to go to zero, all other things that scale with $\delta t$ will also go to zero (compared to things of "finite magnitude"). Since $\delta m$ represents the amount of mass that is added in time $\delta t$, when the latter goes to zero, so does the former. If the rate of mass accretion at a given moment is $R(t)$, then $\delta m = R(t) \delta t$. Do you see it now?

Answer (score 1):

(a) "Why the left side is $mgδt$ rather than $(m+δm)gδt$?". It doesn't really matter, as we shall see, but at this stage it would arguably be better to use the mean mass over the interval $δt$, namely $(m+\frac{\delta m}{2})$ when calculating the gravitational impulse.

(b) Cancelling $mv$ and dividing through by $\delta t$ I get $$(m+\frac{\delta m}{2})g=m \frac{\delta v}{\delta t}+v \frac{\delta m}{\delta t} +\frac{\delta m \delta v}{\delta t}$$

As $\delta t$ approaches zero, so do $\delta v$ and $\delta m$. But the ratios, $\frac{\delta v}{\delta t}$ and $\frac{\delta m}{\delta t}$ remain finite. So in the limit we have $$mg=m \frac{dv}{dt} + v \frac{dm}{dt}.$$

The two terms that disappeared did so because they had an 'extra' $\delta m$ on the top line.